# Multiple file store in database

Tags: database, file-upload

this action is called when i m upload image:

```
    header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
    header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
    header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
    header("Pragma: no-cache");

    $targetDir = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'plupload' ;
    $cleanupTargetDir = true; // Remove old files
    $maxFileAge = 5 * 3600; // Temp file age in seconds
    if (!file_exists($targetDir)) {
        @mkdir($targetDir);
    }       

    if (isset($_REQUEST["name"])) {
    $fileName = $_REQUEST["name"];
    } elseif (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $fileName = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    } else {
    $fileName = uniqid("file_");
    }

    $_SESSION['file'] = $fileName;
    $filePath = $targetDir . DS . $fileName;
    // Chunking might be enabled
    $chunk = isset($_REQUEST["chunk"]) ? intval($_REQUEST["chunk"]) : 0;
    $chunks = isset($_REQUEST["chunks"]) ? intval($_REQUEST["chunks"]) : 0;
    // Remove old temp files    
    if ($cleanupTargetDir) {
    if (!is_dir($targetDir) || !$dir = opendir($targetDir)) {
    die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 100, "message": "Failed to open temp directory."}, "id" : "id"}');
    }
    while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
    $tmpfilePath = $targetDir . DS . $file;
    // If temp file is current file proceed to the next
    if ($tmpfilePath == "{$filePath}.part") {
    continue;
    }
    // Remove temp file if it is older than the max age and is not the current file
    if (preg_match('/\.part$/', $file) && (filemtime($tmpfilePath) < time() - $maxFileAge)) {
    @unlink($tmpfilePath);
    }
    }
    closedir($dir);
    }   
    // Open temp file
    if (!$out = @fopen("{$filePath}.part", $chunks ? "ab" : "wb")) {
    die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 102, "message": "Failed to open output stream."}, "id" : "id"}');
    }
    if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"])) {
    die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 103, "message": "Failed to move uploaded file."}, "id" : "id"}');
    }
    // Read binary input stream and append it to temp file
    if (!$in = @fopen($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "rb")) {
    die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 101, "message": "Failed to open input stream."}, "id" : "id"}');
    }
    } else {    
    if (!$in = @fopen("php://input", "rb")) {
    die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 101, "message": "Failed to open input stream."}, "id" : "id"}');
    }
    }
    while ($buff = fread($in, 4096)) {
    fwrite($out, $buff);
    }
    @fclose($out);
    @fclose($in);
    // Check if file has been uploaded
    if (!$chunks || $chunk == $chunks - 1) {
    // Strip the temp .part suffix off 
    rename("{$filePath}.part", $filePath);
    }
    // Return Success JSON-RPC response
    die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "result" : null, "id" : "id"}');
```

this action is called when i m click on button:

```
    $comment = $_POST['comments1'];

    $id = $_SESSION['id'];
    $time =  date("Y-m-d h:i:s", Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp(time()));
    $conn = Mage::getModel('management/comment');
    $conn->setData('comment',$comment);
    $conn->setData('task_id',$id);
    $conn->setData('time',$time);
    $conn->save();
//  $obj = Mage::getModel('management/comment')->getCollection();
    $cid = $conn->getCommentId();
    $file = $_SESSION['img'];
    $fileName = $_SESSION['file'];
    $type = $_SESSION['type'];

    $conn = Mage::getModel('management/file');
    $conn->setData('filename',$fileName);
    $conn->setData('file',$file);
    $conn->setData('type',$type);
    $conn->setData('comment_id',$cid);
    $conn->setData('task_id',$id);
    $conn->save();
```

In plupload i m upload two or more files n when i m click on button that time i want to store all file in database.

how to store all file in database when i m click on button?

Comment: [Here in this question](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/48849/get-image-url-from-database) you asked for retrieving and told you succeeded now again you are here asking fro uploading?Without uploading images how did you manage to retrieve?

Comment: that was succeed but for only single file store in database now i want to store multiple file in database

Answer (score 1):

Change the code in action when you upload image

```
  $_SESSION['file'] = $fileName;
```

write this code:

```
        if($_SESSION['file'] !=""){
        $fileNameOld = $_SESSION['file'];
        $_SESSION['file'] = $fileNameOld.','.$fileName;
    }
    else{
        $_SESSION['file'] = $fileName;
    }
```

And in another action write this code after query

```
   $_SESSION['file'] = "";
```